# Get URL from HTML code using a regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, url

Consider:

```
<div><a href="http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com/">Anirudha Web blog</a></div>
```

What is the regular expression to get `http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com/`
from the following?

```
<div><a href="http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com/">Anirudha Web blog</a></div>
```

If you suggest something in C# that's good. I also like jQuery to do this.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for processing HTML, it will drive you insane! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @soulmerge, I agree with you, but seems he/she just what to grab url addresses, not parse HTML code

Comment: You don't know that internet url start from http:// https://

Comment: Are you trying to extract links from plain text, or was the `<a href=...` part of the pattern as well?

Comment: whats your latest update to the question supposed to mean?

Comment: @Rubens Farias - The URLs are written in HTML, so the HTML code has to be parsed (and entities decoded, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
href="(.*?)"
```

Ok, let's go with another regex for parsing URLs. This comes from [RFC 2396 - URI Generic Syntax: Parsing a URI Reference with a Regular Expression](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

Of course, you can have relative URL address into your HTML code, you'll need to address them in another way; I can recommend you to use C# [`Uri Constructor (Uri, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91.aspx).

Comment: no thanks but i say for get programmatically means to say regex to get url

Comment: @Gupta, I didn't understood your comment; both are regular expressions.

Comment: Nice try, but (a) *? for minimal munch is FWIS rare among the world's regex flavours (b) too many mistakes in your second regex to begin listing them

Comment: @Stewart, how about this one?

Comment: @Rubens Farias don't worry i say that how can i do it by regex

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery you can do the following.

```
$('a').attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is using the following regular expression.

```
/href="([^"]+)"/
```

This will get all characters from the first quote until it finds a character that is a quote. This is, in most languages, the fastest way to get a quoted string, that can't itself contain quotes. Quotes should be encoded when used in attributes.

**UPDATE**: A complete Perl program for parsing URLs would look like this:

```
use 5.010;

while (<>) {
    push @matches, m/href="([^"]+)"/gi;
    push @matches, m/href='([^']+)'/gi;
    push @matches, m/href=([^"'][^>\s]*)[>\s]+/gi;
    say for @matches;
}
```

It reads from stdin and prints all URLs. It takes care of the three possible quotes. Use it with `curl` to find all the URLs in a webpage:

```
curl url | perl urls.pl
```

Comment: In the wild, HTML can be a deadly thing. href=a.html is "valid," or at least should work just as well as href="a.html" and in most instances special characters that should be escaped aren't *cough* google *cough*

Comment: Correct, there are many pitfalls when using information from the web. On the other hand if I need to find the urls from one webpage on which I can see all possible problems (or find out by testing) I will use this regex (or variant) before using heavier tools. Still, this all depends on the situation and this looks like a Get it Done situation.

Comment: blah... this won't work at all.  Attribute values can have ",' or none delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to load the HTML into the C# XML parser and then use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to query the URLs. This way you don't have to worry about parsing at all.

Comment: Why write when you can link:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shehperu/SimpleXMLParser11292005004801AM/SimpleXMLParser.aspx  is a nice simple example.  http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-xml_cs.html is a more complex one.
But as you can see... all you do is read it into the xml object and then query it with xpath.  you will then have a list of href attributes.  simple.  done.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need a complicated regular expression or HTML parser, since you only want to extract links. Here's a generic way to do it.

```
data="""
<html>
abcd ef ....
blah blah <div><a href="http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com/">Anirudha Web blog</a></div>
blah  ...
<div><a href="http://mike.blogspot.com/">Mike's Web blog
</a></div>
end...
</html>
"""    
for item in data.split("</a>"):
    if "<a href" in item:
        start_of_href = item.index("<a href") # get where <a href=" is
        print item[start_of_href+len('<a href="'):] # print substring from <a href onwards.
```

The above is Python code, but the idea behind you can adapt in your C# language. Split your HTML string using `"</a>"` as delimiter. Go through each split field, check for `"href"`, then get the substr after `"href"`. That will be your links.

Comment: This seems more complex than a regex!

Comment: complex because it has more words? Would you rather look at an essay written in english or one that is encoded with numbers, each number representing a letter? its the same analogy. what regex does behind is roughly the same as what i posted. string manipulations, except that its presented more clearly to the reader, and not having the reader guessing what your code means

Comment: take for example the regex posted by Ruben. seriously, if you can decipher what it means at first glance, i take my hat off you.

Comment: also here you get to make sure the code is optimized.  Who knows what the regex will do... you know </a> is the best place to split the code -- going to be much better than the regex.

Comment: see my comment below -- that is is the "non complex" way to do it.