# How can I extract this text from an HTML page in C#?

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://vk.com/video219171498_166049761");
string Vk_video_resText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
txt.Text = "" + Vk_video_resText + "";
```

How can I take

```
http:\\\/\\\/cs513404v4.vk.me\\\/u3692175\\\/videos\\\/b113808aad.360.mp4\
```

from the HTML page?

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: Are you trying to get that single url or any random url in the html response? If it's the second http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819534/get-url-from-html-code-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: Is there a video in the page you're trying to extract? If so, do you have sample markup?

Comment: No I want to get single url

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all you want to do is strip away all the HTML tags so you're only left with the text.

A lighter weight solution over htmlagilitypack is the code presented in the article [Quick and Easy Method to Remove Html Tags](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/quick-and-easy-method-to-remove-html-tags).

Comment: I don't want to remove i want to take this link

Comment: If the link is not part of a tag, then that's exactly what you'll get.